# Ocultar o encriptar contraseñas en SQLite y Java Web

Tags: jsp, servlets, sqlite3

Existe alguna manera de poder ocultar las contraseñas que registran mis usuarios, para cuando se revise la base de datos se muestre ********* o encriptado, alguna funcion propia de SQLite?

Por otro lado de no haber una función para hacer eso , mi sistema cuenta con un login y registro que funciona, pero las contraseñas están en un string simple, si trabajo la encriptacion en los servlets me gustaría saber que clases debo usar, supongo que para el momento del registro se encripta la contraseña y para el login se desencripta para la autenticacion ?

Comment: Si hay addons pero debes [pagarlos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669905/sqlite-with-encryption-password-protection) aquí hay una [opción](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561104/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-with-my-passphrase-in-java-pc-not-mobile-plat/32583766) o [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554296/simple-java-aes-encrypt-decrypt-example) también puede servirte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo puedes revisar este articulo te puede servir para hacer lo que quieres:

> http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/encrypt-user-password-example-java/

Te muestran diferentes opciones de funciones hechas en Java que te ayudarían a crear y validar contraseñas. Ya que como te comente mas temprano si se puede encriptar en SQLite pero tienes que pagar por el plugin o add-on